# Is it "offensive jokes on" or "offensive jokes against"?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if both forms are ok and mean the same thing. I always thought they were synonymous, but now after asking so many questions, I am no longer sure, because I was proven wrong before on some grammatical matters.

Here's an example:

> A Facebook employee posted offensive jokes on Zuckerberg and got
>   promptly fired.

Comment: I would use *about* in that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While neither is wrong, recently I would expect "on" to be used for the medium, not the subject:

A Facebook employee posted offensive jokes on Twitter and got promptly fired.

But "on X" has  a long history of being used for "about X".

I would expect to see "about" more often than "against". "Against" perhaps would be used when the text is strongly emphasizing the hostile nature of the jokes, and at least implying that the offense was intentional.

Comment: "On" means "about" in many contexts, but "a joke on [someone]" means the joke was a practical one: a prank or hoax of some sort.  "I played a joke on my brother by telling him our parents were divorcing." If the person is merely the subject of verbal or visual humor, it is "about" him.  And jokes are never "against" someone, however brutally a joke may portray him — that's just not the right word.

Comment: @Malvolio yes, "a joke on [someone]" is a very commen usage, but "a joke on [some group]" is not. It isn't quite wrong, but nearly so, in my view. And I have heard "a joke against"  used when accusing someone of making a racially insensitive joke with malice aforethought. In fact i believe I have heard it on a national news broadcast.